# Root directory master page attached to inner folder webform

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a master page `main.master` in root directory and I have created folder name `frms` in root director also.So I want to create web forms in 'frms' folder with attached root directory master page.How can I create or how can I attached?

Comment: Have you even tried? Add new item > web form > web form with master page.

Comment: add new> webform buti I did not find web form with master page

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution
Right click the folder then select  Add >NewItem >WebformusingMaster
after click this it will ask about master page file.Select the file according to your project.